# How to upgrade Windows 7 to Windows 10 Insider Preview?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update, windows-10-upgrade

I heard, that I am able to update my windows 7 to Windows 10 Preview through the `Windows Update Centre`. I tried to find some guide about this, but was unsuccessful. Can you give me a link or instruction, how to perform this update?

P.S. I install all updates in `Windows Update`, but there is no option to Install Windows 10 Preview.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don’t I have the Get Windows 10 icon?](http://superuser.com/questions/922441/why-don-t-i-have-the-get-windows-10-icon)

Comment: @DavidPostill, I don't think so. I have this icon. But it offers to reserver update, but I want to upgrade the system now.

Comment: It's literally the first Google result for "Windows 10 preview". http://windows.microsoft.com/en-nz/windows/preview-iso

Comment: @MichaelFrank, yep. I read this link. But there I can download a disk image, but I want to upgrade my system from the Update Center.

Comment: That's how it works. Put the ISO on a USB and run the installer from within Windows.

Comment: @MichaelFrank, why I cannot update Windows from the center? Few months ago, I was able to update my system from center. Am I correct, that at present this function is disabled?

Comment: That's because it's still in preview. There's no option in Windows Update because it is not an update for Windows.

Comment: @MichaelFrank, I was wrong. There is a update Windows from Windows Update. If you sign in on http://windows.microsoft.com/en-nz/windows/preview-iso and press the button "start update", then your Windows Update Center will offer you to download the update (2.4 GB).

Comment: The preview is just a beta, it's not ready for prime time and will expire shortly.  You don't need to replace your working OS for the preview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are searching for a way to download and install the Insider Preview (the not finished product) then follow this:

1. First, you will need a Microsoft account. If you have a Hotmail or Outlook e-mail account, then you already have a Microsoft account.
2. Go to the [Windows Insider](https://insider.windows.com/) web page and click on the "Get started" button.
3. Follow the steps on the web page until you reach a page where you can choose to download Windows 10 Preview for PC.
4. Download it and install it.

[image: screenshot]

In my opinion the web page is very self-explanatory and easy to use.

If you are looking for the free upgrade to Windows 10 (the finished product) then you should look for a small Windows logo in your Notification area (a.k.a. the System tray). If you click that icon you can reserve a copy of Windows 10. But you won't get it until the end of July.

Hopefully this helped you with finding what you wanted.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to the http://windows.microsoft.com/en-nz/windows/preview-iso.
2. Sign up there.
3. Download `Windows10InsiderPreview.exe` and install it.
4. Go to the `Windows Update Center` and `Check for updates`.
5. Start Windows 10 update process.

Comment: Good find. I knew I had seen this before, but as I couldn't find it anymore I figured it had been removed in favour of the ISO installer.

Comment: I am confused... "Click one of the Download links on this page to download a special file—it's called an ISO file—that you can use to install the preview." There is no EXE file as far as I can tell. If I recall correctly the EXE files were available only initially. I wouldn't really know, because I have been using ISO files since the first public release.

Comment: Judging by the instructions provided here, it appears as if the aforementioned EXE file is only used to install a special update (with a KB number I don't recall right now) through the Windows Update, to then push out the Windows 10 Technical Preview on an installed and running Windows 7 or 8.x system. Microsoft uses this as a mechanism for Windows Insider users to opt-in and install the preview on top of an installed system. This update is not part of the regular Windows Update channel, so only users who run the EXE and install it will get the preview, as an upgrade.

Comment: I personally always prefer doing a clean install using ISO files. The installation is much faster, and the installed system end up being much snappier and faster, and I end up being much happier.

Comment: If and when installing the preview as an upgrade on top of an installed Windows system, or otherwise doing a clean install, remember to create a system backup. Follow the instructions on the site to create a recovery media if you don't have a recovery partition prepared on your computer.

Comment: @sammyg, I have already successfully updated from Windows 7 to Windows 10.

Comment: Are you talking about the preview (test) version or the final (finished product) version of Windows 10?

Comment: @sammyg, I talk about Windows 10 Insider Preview.

Comment: OK. So how did that happen, exactly? Did you run the EXE file or did you use the ISO file?

Comment: @sammyg, I installed `Windows10InsiderPreview.exe`. Then I go to `Microsoft Download Center` and start `Windows 10 update`. I didn't download any ISO files.

Comment: OK. So you essentially did an in-place upgrade inside Windows 7? But where is the EXE file? I can't find it and it's not on the page you linked to. Did you do it recently or a long time ago?

Comment: @sammyg, I did it yesterday. Yes, I update Windows 7 in-place. Windows 7 downloads Windows 10, extract it and then reboot itself. You need sign uo on https://insider.windows.com/ Then, you say, that you want to download Windows 10 for Desktop, and This site allows you to download this exe file.

Comment: That's interesting. Because I don't see that option when I sign in on the site. I have been registered for a long time. I have always used the ISO files. I sometimes allow the build updates (upgrade really) to be done in-place, even if it takes time. I have a multi-boot configuration. But it's good to know that the EXE option is still available, even if it does not appear to be available to me. Could it be because I am visiting the site using Windows Vista at the moment? It would not surprise me. Because they can detect the OS and the upgrade option is not available to Windows Vista users.

Comment: @sammyg, Yes, you're absolutely right. You can update only windows 7 or higher to windows 10.