# Windows 10 icon not displayed

Tags: windows, icons

After a repair to my Windows 7 (led by a Microsoft Support engineer) my Windows 10 icon is no longer showing. I have installed all the latest updates, nothing is blocked and my Windows is genuine.

Comment: [Do you have the required update, that manages the installation of this tool, installed?](http://superuser.com/questions/922441/why-don-t-i-have-the-get-windows-10-icon)

Comment: [You can also start the application manually if you want.  There exists articles that describe how to kill or remove the icon, you can use that information, to manually make the icon appear ( if the update is installed ).](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/578100/remove-the-get-windows-10-icon-from-the-icon-tray/)

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to know what the engineer has done.

There are a few things you can try

1. Update all Windows updates (as you say you have)
2. Right click near the clock in your task bar and choose `Customize Notifications Area` - ensure it's not hidden
3. Ensure [KB3035583](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/3035583) is installed