# No Windows 10 Upgrade icon in Windows 7 running in Parallels

Tags: windows-7, parallels, windows-10-upgrade

**Clarification: while this question is very much related to other questions regarding Windows 10, it also covers specific aspects relating to using Parallels Desktop. These aspects are not covered in other questions; therefore, this question is not a duplicate.**

I have Windows 7 Ultimate running on my Mac (OS X 10.10.4) via Parallels Desktop 10.2.0.

I want to upgrade to Windows 10, but I don't seem to have the upgrade icon in the system tray. I've run Windows Update multiple times, but no joy. I've also tried everything at http://www.cnet.com/uk/how-to/how-to-get-the-windows-10-upgrade-icon-if-its-missing/ and at http://www.askvg.com/fix-get-windows-10-upgrade-app-icon-is-missing-in-taskbar/.

I can confirm that GWX.exe is present in C:\WINDOWS\System32, but when I try to run it (either via the command line or through the GUI) nothing happens.

What should I try next? I'm confident I've tried all the standard troubleshooting steps for this, so is there perhaps something about Parallels that means the upgrade process will work differently?

Comment: This has been asked [numerous](http://superuser.com/questions/922441/why-don-t-i-have-the-get-windows-10-icon) times.  One of the conditions for the icon to appear, is false, up to you to determine which one it is.

Comment: I've read through those questions. But none of them seem to refer to running a virtual install of Windows 7, so I thought I'd ask my question independently. I've clearly gone through the basic troubleshooting steps, as indicated by the two links I've included above. I'd like to know if there's anything else I should try, or if there is a specific reason why this doesn't work with Parallels.

Comment: I found [this](https://forum.parallels.com/threads/windows-10-update-reservation-icon.328622/) on the Parallels forums. There seems to be a solution there, you could try that.

Comment: Thank you, @MC10! Precisely the sort of answer I was looking for. I'm inferring from that link that perhaps GWX doesn't work in Parallels 9 because Parallels isn't definitely compatible with Windows 10. Would you agree that that sounds about right?

Comment: @Jim - Windows isn't aware its on a virtual machine.  So unless the license isn't valid and the installation activated, the icon should appear, I have multiple virtual machines that didn't have a problem getting the icon.  You should run the Compatibility Appraiser to determine that.

Comment: Thanks for the info, @Ramhound. I appreciate your logic, but I can confirm that the license is valid (I think I even have the box upstairs, and probably the receipt, too) and the installation is activated. So, it must be something else.

Comment: @Jim - You have ran the script?  The Parallel's community thread, a user indicates, the script solved the problem for them.  Of course the problem of Parallels 9 not supporting Windows 10 is separate from this problem.  The solution to that problem is simple, use a version of Parallels that does support Windows 10.

Comment: The script that's hosted on Dropbox? Yes, I've run that script (it's linked to by the CNET link in my original question)

Comment: @Jim - There is an improved script.  The one in Karan's answer....The link thread has some manual mitigation you can try also.

Comment: Thank you! I've just re-read the second article I linked to above, and re-read my registry settings. Someone (perhaps because I've now read the Parallels community thread) I've noticed the presence of the "Reduced" key, which seems to imply that Windows doesn't think my hardware is compatible with Windows 10, and that I should expect the icon to appear on July 29th. I'll report back after that :)

Comment: So it's July 29th, and the Windows 10 upgrade icon has appeared in my Win7 install running under Parallels. I'm guessing that my thinking was right, and that at least some Parallels setups are not guaranteed to run Windows 10.

Comment: Further update: Parallels Desktop 11 has been released, and has support for Win10 as a guest operating system. I am not sure if this means that Win10 will never be supported by earlier versions of Parallels, but it does give a solution to my problem. I don't seem to have sufficient privileges to add this as an answer!