# Is it possible to upgrade to Windows 10 from Windows 8 rather than 8.1?

Tags: windows-10-upgrade, windows-10

Is it possible to upgrade to Windows 10 from Windows 8 without the 8.1 update?

My system failed to update to 8.1 many times so I skipped the update. Some time has passed so I tried again, now and from the Windows store when I tried to update to 8.1 and it says applications installed.

I plan a clean install of Windows 10 anyhow so do I have to first upgrade to Windows 8.1 in order to qualify for the free update?

--

**Update:** In the end I downloaded the 8.1 media and did a clean install, at the end of the install it told me a new version of windows was available and carried on straight into the windows 10 install.

This froze at 32% and after research to be the same issue I used to have with the 8.1 install freezing. After disconnecting the internet connections and all peripherals the windows 10 install worked.

Comment: If you can't cleanly upgrade 8 to 8.1 then upgrading to 10 probably won't work anyway. Figure out what's broken about your Windows 8 install first, fix it, get 8.1 installed, and then go to 10.

Comment: You **can** do an in-place upgrade from Windows 8.0 to 10, even though it may not be advisible.

Comment: You can upgrade to Windows 8.0 to Windows 10. It just requires you perform a clean install. When basically means you cannot do an in-place upgrade. This means all personal files, application settings, and programs will be deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your upgrade to 8.1 failed then you need to look up what error codes mean, I documented my issues with the 8.1 upgrade here on this site as much as I could.

A **shortcut is to reinstall from Windows 8.1 refresh media**, but keeping your data. I just did that and and was greeted by the Windows 10 upgrade offer even before the Windows 8 setup finished. So I installed Windows two times in a row, but I had a lot less hassle than trying to understand and fix some of the error codes I got, where I though I already solved them with 8.1.

More detail and links in my aswer here: [Do I need to have an updated Windows 8 / 8.1 to update to Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/a/947155/252532)

Answer (score 2):

Although Microsoft states that you must be running Windows 7 or Windows 8.1 I was able to update from Windows 8 without any issues.

Due to some difficulties with upgrading my old installation I did a fresh install of Windows 8 and then I upgraded to Windows 10 right after without updating to Windows 8.1 first.