# Windows 10 update now showing on windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, window

I am using windows 8. Windows 10 update not showing while windows 8.1 update showing in store.
Should i update my windows 8 to 8.1 first? or can i get direct windows 10 update?

Comment: Related: [Why don’t I have the Get Windows 10 icon?](http://superuser.com/questions/922441/why-don-t-i-have-the-get-windows-10-icon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The free windows 10 upgrade is only available if you are running 8.1 or 7.  Windows 8 users need to upgrade to windows 8.1 update and install all windows updates before the "Ger Windows 10 App" will appear.

Quote from http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/windows-10-faq

> The only requirements are that a) your device is compatible, and b) you’re running genuine Windows 7 Service Pack 1 (SP1) or Windows 8.1 (Update).

Backed up by the upgrade paths:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To be eligible for the update: "If you're running Windows 8, you'll have to bump it up to 8.1. To do that, click the Store tile on the Start screen; inside the store, you should see an icon for the update." - Source [here](http://www.theverge.com/2015/7/28/9060737/microsoft-windows-10-upgrade-how-to-guide)

To install this update, you must have April 2014 update rollup for Windows RT 8.1, Windows 8.1, and Windows Server 2012 R2 (2919355) installed in Windows 8.1
Source [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/3035583)