# "Get Windows 10" Icon when clicked , does nothing

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade

I know I am way too late to windows 10 but there is no harm in asking .I am using Windows 7 32 bit and I got the "Get Windows 10"  icon just an hour ago and when i click on it .....nothing happens , other than the Laptop getting slower and the arrival of a process called GWXUX.exe in the task manager . but thats it , nothing else . And if the icon does  work , will i be able to install windows 10 ? My PC is also Arabic if that makes any difference . I tried the solution **[HERE](https://superuser.com/questions/922441/why-don-t-i-have-the-get-windows-10-icon)** , but it did not help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the "Get Windows 10" application is not working all you have to do is wait until after [November 10th](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_cortana/when-will-conrtana-available-in-india/b875cfba-6c2f-4f2d-82cd-0a56e98ed857?auth=1)
 2015.  In an effort to outline how Windows 10 will be delivered to users eligible for the free upgrade Microsoft stated the following recently.

> We will soon be publishing Windows 10 as an “Optional Update” in
>   Windows Update for all Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 customers. Windows
>   Update is the trusted, logical location for our most important
>   updates, and adding Windows 10 here is another way we will make it
>   easy for you to find your upgrade.

They went on to explain what will happen next year.

> Early next year, we expect to be re-categorizing Windows 10 as a
>   “Recommended Update”. Depending upon your Windows Update settings,
>   this may cause the upgrade process to automatically initiate on your
>   device. Before the upgrade changes the OS of your device, you will be
>   clearly prompted to choose whether or not to continue. And of course,
>   if you choose to upgrade (our recommendation!), then you will have 31
>   days to roll back to your previous Windows version if you don’t love
>   it.

Starting with the Threshold 2 update Windows 10 will be able to be activated with your Windows 7, Windows 8, or Windows 8.1 license.  The Windows 10 Threshold 2 .ISO will both accept an eligible license key at installation and if that step is simply skipped Windows 10 will also accept and activate with those same keys.

> We have received a lot of feedback from Insiders on making it easier
>   to activate Windows 10 on devices that take advantage of the free
>   upgrade offer to genuine Windows by using existing Windows 7, Windows
>   8 or Windows 8.1 product keys. If you install this build of the
>   Windows 10 on a PC and it doesn't automatically
>   activate, you can enter the product key from Windows 7, Windows 8 or
>   Windows 8.1 used to activate the prior Windows version on the same
>   device to activate Windows 10 by going to Settings > Update & security
>   Activation and selecting Change Product Key. If you do a clean install of Windows 10 by booting off the media, you can also enter the product key from prior Windows versions on qualifying devices during
>   setup.

It makes sense that the changes to how Windows 10 is distributed will also come around that same time.

*I slightly modified the quote by removing the reference to the Insider Build, this has been a confirm feature of Threshold 2, which is being released on November 2nd.*

[Source](http://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2015/10/29/making-it-easier-to-upgrade-to-windows-10/)

[Threshold 2 - Source](http://www.zdnet.com/article/next-big-windows-10-release-will-ease-activation-hassles/)

If you cannot wait then you should one of the following

1. Download the [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) to create the .ISO yourself
2. [Download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench) the .ISO yourself.

You don't need the "Get Windows 10" application in order to perform the upgrade. I should point out, if your current installation is not genuine, the installation of Windows 10 will not activate.  As I pointed out if you simply wait, Windows 10 will be offered to you, even if you don't opt into the update.

Answer (score 1):

Get Windows 10 Media Creation Tool from here : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

It will allow you to upgrade your computer to Windows 10 or create bootable installation medias for  other computers you might have.