# How does Microsoft push Windows 10 Upgrade?

Tags: windows, updates

A little while ago I turned on my gaming computer and noticed the following window on my taskbar.

[image: Windows 10 Upgrade]

When I click it, I get the following window.

[image]

If I had my update settings turned off. Would they still be able to push the upgrade notification?

Comment: Kinda a SuperUser.SE question.

Comment: Yes As its just a notification not an actual update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pushed via [KB3035583](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3035583) as mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/a/922069/138343). If you never install that update (or uninstall it) then you won't see the notifications, simple.