# How to permanently set up "Only show notifications" for Windows 10 Update notifications icon in the tray?

Tags: windows, notifications, windows-10-upgrade

I know how to disable "Additional capabilities for Windows Update notifications in Windows 8.1 and Windows 7 SP1" ([inter alia through Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/922068/how-to-disable-the-get-windows-10-icon-shown-in-the-notification-area-tray)) but I prefer just to set it up in "Only show notifications" mode. Unfortunately it is back to "Show icon and notifications" after OS restart :/

Is it possible to set it up permanently in "Only show notifications" mode?

I'm thinking about adding to autostart a command-line script that can set up "Only show notifications" for GWX.exe, but I can not ask Google a good question. Is it possible to set up the tray icon display behavior from the command-line?

Edited:
**It seems that MS fixed it - its keeps "Only show notifications" after restart**

Comment: Does selecting "only show notifications" actually work till you restart? According to many it doesn't so if the app ignores the setting completely then there's not much one can do really.

Comment: @Karan: W8.1 - for me it works until OS restart.

Comment: You can try and automate it using something like AutoHotkey then.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing in Windows 7, although I've never noticed this happening in the past.