# Preventing Windows 10 From Being Installed On My Windows 7 Desktop PC?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I am quite content with using Windows 7 on my desktop PC, and do not wish to install Windows 10 at this time.

To ensure that Windows 10 does not install, what measures can I immediately take (I note there is a white Windows icon in the system tray) or look out for (in terms of Windows Updates) to prevent it from being installed on my PC ?

Comment: You uninstall the updates that install the "Get Windows 10" application, you don't indicate any desire for it when prompted, and you simply don't install it.  The upgrade if offered would be in Windows Update, you can hide it like any other update, feel free to do that.

Comment: @Ramhound In terms of the Windows Update, will it specifically say any thing like "Windows 10 Upgrade ......" ?

Comment: The specific name of the update escapes me, there are questions that exists, with screenshot of the update though.  What the update is will be pretty specific, besides, if you don't reserve/indicate you want the upgrade it won't even be downloaded.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for that. When you mean reserved, as in going to the Microsoft website and reserving it ?

Comment: @Ramhound Answered below I believe.

Comment: No;  I mentioned the process in my very first comment.  There are currently dozens of questions on the process itself, those questions like "how you reserve Windows 10", already have answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to prevent this is just to not reserve your upgrade. If `GetWindowsX` doesn't reserve Windows 10, it won't instruct Windows Update that there is an update titled `Install Windows 10 <version>`. Therefore, if you don't reserve, you won't get the upgrade through Windows Update.

**EDIT:** If you've reserved your upgrade, You will see `We'll let you know when Windows 10 is ready to download` from within Windows Update

Comment: AFAIK I haven't reserved it ?

Comment: @Simon If you've clicked on the little white Windows logo, and clicked `Reserve Your Free Upgrade` you have reserved it, otherwise, no, you haven't.

Comment: Ah fine, no I haven't :) How do I get rid of that white Windows logo in the system tray ?

Comment: @Simon to get rid of it, navigate to: `C:\Windows\System32\GWX` (or if I didn't remember correctly, `C:\Windows\GWX`) and delete everything in that folder.

Comment: Fine, What is GWX referring to ?

Comment: @Simon `GWX` is `GetWindowsX` or rather; `GetWindows10`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Would another way be to remove the GWX icon from the system tray: click on
"show hidden icons" > "customise", scroll to GWX and select " hide
icon and notifications". Or would that just be hiding and not removing ?

Comment: @Simon Let's continue this discussion in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/26460/discussion-between-td-512-and-simon?tab=general)

Comment: Couldn't type for some reason in chat. Maybe next time :)

Comment: @Simon try again. I fixed it :)

Comment: @Simon See this related Su question: [How to disable the “Get Windows 10” icon shown in the notification area (tray)?](http://superuser.com/questions/922068/how-to-disable-the-get-windows-10-icon-shown-in-the-notification-area-tray)

Answer (score 0):

You can also just go into your Windows Update option in Control Panel and select the "Check for updates but let me choose whether to download and install them" option.