# How to Abort Windows 10 Upgrade Prompt on Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, unwanted-application

Windows 10 files have already been downloaded and a Windows Update prompt which can't be killed in Task Manager, or seemingly from anywhere else, is giving me the option of either scheduling the upgrade for later or doing it right now.

I want to hold off indefinitely and so I've left it as is without confirming a date or time for the last handful of days and I haven't rebooted since as I'm afraid if I do it'll start the upgrade. A fellow user, Mark Berry, was able to get his customer's PC to stop trying to upgrade to Windows 10 here [Tell Windows 7 to Stop Trying to Upgrade to Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/951277/tell-windows-7-to-stop-trying-to-upgrade-to-windows-10) but it was a Windows 7 machine. I'm on Windows 8.1 and the registry values do not mirror Win 7's 100%. Is this method also possible on Windows 8.1? If so, which values do I need to delete or modify and are there any other steps I need to take prior to doing so?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that your computer will not upgrade on restart and will just prompt you that it's ready to install every time you log in. (I'm stuck in the same situation)

That being said, it even reverted back to having to download again after a couple of days of not installing.

I haven't been able to check if you can stop the upgrade indefinitely, but I can confirm this registery edit to work: http://winsupersite.com/windows-10/disabling-windows-10-upgrade-notification

Answer (score 0):

This is now easy with [Never 10](https://www.grc.com/never10.htm), a portable utility to prevent Windows 10 upgrades.