# Cannot delay 'Upgrade to Windows 10' prompt

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

I've already established a schedule to have my Windows 8.1 pc upgraded to Windows 10.  I've set the schedule 3 days from now, however, only a few short hours later and it is prompting me to restart my system immediately for the installation as opposed to the date "agreed" on.

Why does the upgrade window keep pestering me?

Comment: I had the same problem and just turned off automatic upgrades. One of these days, when I have three days to spare, I'll do a clean install from the ISO (three days because that's how long it takes me to reinstall all my apps).

Comment: possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/951277/tell-windows-7-to-stop-trying-to-upgrade-to-windows-10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Just like internet explorer, it keeps asking if I want it as default
>   browser even if I check the 'don't ask again'...

For a solution try the following steps (one at a time) and see if the 'pestering' stops:

- Click customize in the system tray and turn off the Get Windows 10
  app notification.
- Go to windows updates and uninstall `KB3035583`
- Open up regedit.exe using the Start search or by hitting WIN + R and
  pasting it into the field. Then browse down to the following key,
  creating it if it doesn’t exist:
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Gwx`

  Once you are there, create a new 32-bit DWORD value on the right-hand side named DisableGwx, and give it a value of 1

Comment: @cyberweb poweruser - Did I help You solve the problem? If yes, You can accept it as an answer. If You have further problems, feel confident to ask.