# Postpone install of Windows 10 for 1 month?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I currently run Windows 7, and I reserved a copy of Windows 10. I got a prompt that it is ready to install yesterday, but when it asks what date to schedule the installation for; you can only choose within the next 3 days.

I've read online that there are a number of teething problems (as there always tend to be) - and I want to delay the installation for 4 weeks while any bugs are ironed out.

I use my laptop for programming work and it must be a stable environment; but I *don't* want to delete the install files/not do the upgrade. I do want to upgrade, but in a month's time.

Is it possible?

**Not a duplicate:** The other question deals with how to permanently get rid of the upgrade. I just want to delay it for a month. I've posted an answer which follows much different steps to the other question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tell Windows 7 to Stop Trying to Upgrade to Windows 10?](http://superuser.com/questions/951277/tell-windows-7-to-stop-trying-to-upgrade-to-windows-10)

Comment: @magicandre1981 That question asks about *permanently* not installing it. I just want to delay it. If I go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\OSUpgrade\State\OSUpgradeStateTimeStamp` it shows a date 2-3 days ago, not the 'postpone til' date. **This isn't a duplicate!**

Comment: Read the **whole** thread starting at [Delaying Windows 10 Upgrade installation for several months](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/delaying-windows-10-upgrade-installation-for/ff6f543f-245b-4429-b04c-d5ba4862ca83?page=1&tm=1440148475358)

Comment: Simplest solution.  Perform the steps to delay it permanently  but save the two hidden folders in another location.  Simplest solution of course is download the Media Creation Tool and create a .ISO today and delay it permanently to save your storage space.  When you are ready to upgrade just burn and/or create a bootable USB disk and choose "upgrade now" option.

Comment: You could try disabling windows update automatic updates and manually doing updates yourself. No idea if this works though :(

Comment: Will try `net stop wuauserv` and disabling the service startup from Automatic to Disabled and report back - thanks!

Comment: In the end I kept getting nagged to postpone for 3 days, every day. I did this about 3 days on the run. The 4th day my PC decided to reboot by itself. As all my running programs were closing, I got another nag screen saying "58 mins left til upgrade". By the time it rebooted it wanted to upgrade and there was no turning back! Ah well, I'm on Windows 10 now and (touch wood) no problems.