# Update Windows 8.1 without Upgrade to Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, upgrade

I have Windows 8.1 and I want to install updates via Windows Update. But whenever I choose updates to download and install, it start downloading Windows 10 Upgrade! I also hide "Upgrade to Windows 10 Pro" update from updates list, and try again, but it does not work and it starts to downloading Windows 10 upgrade.
How can I fix this?

Comment: See also [Tell Windows 7 to Stop Trying to Upgrade to Windows 10?](http://superuser.com/q/951277)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Windows Update, then View Update History. Click on Installed Updates, and use the search box to look for 'kb3035583.' This is the specific (and previously installed) update that wants to download Windows 10 all the time. Right click, and you can choose to uninstall it or hide it. If you want nothing to do with Windows 10 yet, I would just uninstall it.

After doing this, you will have to double check with future updates that it is not showing back up on the list *before* you update.