# Prevent from installation of unwanted upgrade updates in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-upgrade

Windows 7: I twice uninstalled Update for Miscrosoft Windows KB3035583, but it was repeatedly installed, although it has been marked "Hide update". Additionally, settings for install updates was set "Check for updates but let me choose whether to download and install them" - so Windows completely ignored this settings.
Also, although I marked optional update "Upgrade to Windows 10 Home" as "Hide update", the checkbox was unmarked by itself after short time, even without rebooting PC. How to reliably disable this updates?

I applied the following keys, but it's still not helped:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\OSUpgrade]
"AllowOSUpgrade"=dword:00000000
"ReservationsAllowed"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\OSUpgrade\State]
"OSUpgradeState"=dword:00000001
"OSUpgradeStateTimeStamp"="2015-08-06 19:53:58"
```

**Edit:** I tried play with update settings, changed it from "Check for updates but let me choose.." to "Never check for updates", then after some time changed it back to "Check for updates but let me choose.." - and seems this helped. KB2952664 has been moved from "Important" to "Optional" updates, and KB3035583 disappeared completely, and none of updates has been marked for installation. Also picture on Windows Update page has changed color from orange alert color to normal green. So, it seems, this issue somehow linked with Windows Update Client functionality.

Comment: Not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Create the

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Gwx
```

key if it doesn't exist already, then underneath it create the

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Gwx\DisableGwx
```

32-bit DWORD with a value of 1, reboot, profit.

Comment: There is no GWX.EXE process in Task Manager. Should I follow this [method](http://superuser.com/questions/951277/tell-windows-7-to-stop-trying-to-upgrade-to-windows-10) first?

Comment: You may, but the method I posted worked for me like a charm.

Comment: One update - KB2952664 (Compatibility update for upgrading Windows 7) still unmarked by itself and reappearing as "important update" for installation.

Comment: I applied the Gwx key you posted (and few other keys at the top of my post), but KB2952664 and KB3035583 updates still mark themselves as important updates, ready for installation (and will be installed automatically if I set "Install updates automatically").

Comment: The solution that helped is at the end of my question.