# How is the forced Windows 10 upgrade installed when the planned installation day is reached?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade

A friend has a Windows 7 computer and at every boot the Windows 10 upgrade tool asked to install Windows 10. My friend doesn't want Windows 10 at all and hence she dismissed this popup. The upgrade tool has then planned the automatic upgrade to April 29th (two days ago). Since then, the computer hasn't been booted yet.

The installation files for Windows 10 may have already been downloaded on the disk and are waiting for being installed.

What happens when she boots her computer? Will Windows 10 be installed right during boot or can she still intervene, e.g. "Upgrade to Windos 10 now?" -> "Cancel!" ?

**Edit:**

I would not consider my question a duplicate of this linked question. 
[Tell Windows 7 to Stop Trying to Upgrade to Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/951277/tell-windows-7-to-stop-trying-to-upgrade-to-windows-10)

It does not specifically answer the question, whether the upgrade will happen directly during the next boot of Windows 7. If it does, the solution in the linked question is not applicable.

Please also see this article on microsoft.com: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3095675

It states, that if a user cancels the upgrade dialog, the upgrade will happen at the scheduled time.

Comment: After reading the MS article it is not clear what happens if you just cancel without changing the schedule date, I have read where W7 upgrades on it own without any user interaction, people wake up the next day to find w10 installed without being asked. It would be better to reschedule (change the date) when it upgrades if you do not want to do it now.

Answer (score -1):

You could boot from a Linux Live Disk and remove the Windows 10 Update files. They are stored in `C:\$Windows.~BT\Sources`.

For more information see: http://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-turn-your-windows-10-upgrade-into-an-iso/

Comment: I also considered this method as a means to interrupt any upgrade attempt. I am interested in the reason for the downvote and the user may comment his objection.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: @DavidPostill better?

Comment: @Motte001 Hmm. deleting the update files is not mentioned in the link in the answer ...

Comment: @DavidPostill It is not, the link is how you can make an .iso file from the win10 upgrade files. But instead of burning them, you can delete them