# Windows 10 is about to install - Any way to stop it?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-upgrade

I've been avoiding the Windows 10 Upgrade to my Windows 7 install, but after a reboot recently, I am now getting the following notice from Windows Update: 
[image: Windows 10 Ready to install upon reboot]

Is there any way to back out at this point before I reboot? I would like to hold off for a while until I am sure a few legacy applications can handle it.

Comment: Uninstall the update mentioned here and get rid of GWX: http://superuser.com/questions/922068/how-to-disable-the-get-windows-10-icon-shown-in-the-notification-area-tray Then delete the `$Windows.~BT` and `$Windows.~WS` folders. I still see that but every time I restart there is no upgrade that occurs.

Answer (score 4):

Click Start, type: *view installed updates*.
Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>,
look through the list for the *KB3035583* update.
*Right click* it and click *Uninstall*

or

**If I change my mind, can I cancel my reservation?**
Yes, you can cancel your reservation at any time prior to installing Windows 10. Here’s how:
Right click on the Get Windows 10 App or Windows icon located in right end of the taskbar.
Select “Check your upgrade status”
Select “Cancel reservation”
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-faq

Comment: At the point I'm at, there is no longer a "Cancel reservation" option. http://i.imgur.com/NZGd8kK.png

Comment: Same here, there's no option to "Cancel reservation"