# Is GWX technically malware?

Tags: windows-7, malware

GWX, otherwise known as the "Get Windows 10" popup, acts suspiciously similar to malware, except that it is made by Microsoft.

Like malware, GWX:

- installs itself without the user's consent as an "important" update
- downloads and "preloads" 6 GB worth of Windows 10 installation files without the user's consent
- constantly nags the user about downloading Windows 10
- actively prevents the user from disabling it permanently
- changes its behavior through the addition of undocumented features to further prevent its disabling
- requires a special, third-party tool to be removed completely from a system
- advertises another product, even if Windows 7 users get it for free
- is a potentially unwanted program (PUP).

Even TechRadar refers to GWX Control Panel's constant development as an ["uphill battle"](http://www.techradar.com/us/news/software/operating-systems/microsoft-continues-using-heavy-handed-tactics-to-push-windows-10-upgrade-1310752) as random updates seem to push new versions of GWX (with new tricks) to Windows 7 computers.

So, can GWX be considered malware?

Comment: In my opinion, yes it is malware. I then disabled automatic Windows updates and didn't install any updates without checking what they do first (under the assumption that Microsoft doesn't outright lie about what each update does, of course...)

Comment: @user20574 Given that oh so many KB articles about recent updates only say something like "this is important, but we don't bother telling you for what", you are not left with many updates to install

Comment: I overall agree with you - especially the preloading without consent is problematic, for example if your internet connection is subject to a data cap (yes these exists). However removal isn't too bad (though it reappears at least once on occassion) - just remove and hide the appropriate Windows Update: KB3035583 
However: I would actually accuse Microsoft of lying and being actively deceitful as at no point are you warned that several GB will be downloaded without your consent. The Update itself just claims a few hundred KB.

Comment: Voting to close this as 'opinion-based'. I don't see any good can come of it, it's just going to turn into a rant-fest better suited to a chat forum.

Comment: A key point of malware is that if the user knew the implications he would refuse to install the software. That is the case here for many users. In fact that makes it kind of a scam.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen That's why you Google them.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen's right. It _really_ annoys me that updates are not clearly labelled. They're just "this is an important security update". How is that allowing me to make an informed decision about whether to install it? It's deliberately not, is the answer to that.

Comment: I'd say Windows itself IS malware...

Comment: I am not satisfied with the answers posted. Anyone who would like to vote to reopen is welcome to do so. (In retrospect, I should have forced the question open by putting a bounty on it.)

Comment: @oldmud0 - A moderator can cancel a bounty.  So you doing that would have just got a moderator involved.  In other words your question would still have been closed.  Besides a moderator vote to close, caused this question to be closed, so a bounty wouldn't have prevented that.

Comment: @Ramhound, please read the dates next time before telling me something I already know. Thank you.

Comment: @oldmud0 - Everyone replies to my year old comments, why can't I do the same, to other people when their question is in the review queue?

Answer (score 8):

I would call it a rather irritating annoyance, but not malware - neither technically nor substantially.

`installs itself without the user's consent as an "important" update`

Only if you have "important" updates set to automatically install. Otherwise, you have the chance to review the list of pending updates, and uncheck (or hide for good) [KB 3035583](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3035583) which installs the "Get Windows 10" applet.

Needless to say, once you *did* enable auto-install of "important" updates, you waived your option to choose, and left it to Microsoft to decide what's "important".

`actively prevents the user from disabling it permanently`

There are several well documented ways to get rid of KB 3035583 if you installed it by accident, see for example [How to disable the “Get Windows 10” icon shown in the notification area (tray)?](https://superuser.com/questions/922068/how-to-disable-the-get-windows-10-icon-shown-in-the-notification-area-tray) or [How to remove Windows 10 upgrade updates in Windows 7 and 8](http://www.ghacks.net/2015/04/17/how-to-remove-windows-10-upgrade-updates-in-windows-7-and-8/).

Comment: There are well-documented ways to become root on Android, but we can still say Android actively prevents you from becoming root.

Comment: One of the issues is Microsoft randomly decides to re-enable automatic updates every once in a while without letting you know. For example, this happens when you enable Microsoft Update from within Windows Update. So no, you don't necessarily waive the right to choose; sometimes they waive your right for you.

Comment: @Mehrdad Microsoft Update is a superset of - and requires - Windows Update, so it's not a total surprise that enabling Microsoft Update may in fact change the Windows Update settings. Just as anecdotal evidence, I have always had Windows Update set to "never check" on my computers, *and* the `wuAuServ` service set to "manual" startup. I have seen neither updates reset to "auto" nor the service starting on its own, ever. Again, this is just my experience on a handful of computers and VMs. YMMV of course.

Comment: @dxiv: Well it was one hell of a surprise for me. My mileage definitely has varied from yours!

Answer (score 7):

there is no objective definition of malware, so as such you are free to consider it what you want. The best definition I've found is here at the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/malware), but it includes subjective elements.

The code security industry has to make decisions on what is and what isn't malware by their assessment, as do legislatures around the world, and while those definitions may contain terms that describe GWX, the vast majority of users do not believe it to in fact be malicious, so no major entities are likely to determine it to be such.

Comment: How do you know that the vast majority of users do not believe it to be malicious?

Comment: I asked them ;-)

Comment: @FrankThomas Majority of 67 000 000 users at Jul 31?!? 8-          ) I'm imperssed ;-)

Comment: @g2mk Oh common, you only need to ask a representative sample to get a decent idea. My experience mirrors oldmud0's. Most folks do not consider GWX to be malicious. In fact, most folks I've dealt with have happily taken up the Win10 offer and are pleased to have something for nothing. As for me personally, GWX annoys the hell out of me. As does MS. I'm fascinated by just how much abuse the average Joe is happy to take these days. I guess iOS and Android started it, normalized it, and now MS can do whatever it wants.

Comment: @misha256 I just have joked - I have visualized FrankThomas asking all that people. More seriously: 67*10^6 > W7/W8 updaters >> aware W7/W8 updaters.

Comment: @g2mk Lol, I'm so sorry, now that you mention it it's pretty obvious. You even end your comment with a wink. I think I seriously need sleep :-p

Answer (score 4):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malware):

> Malware, short for malicious software, is any software used to disrupt computer operations, gather sensitive information, or gain access to private computer systems. Malware is defined by its malicious intent, acting against the requirements of the computer user, and does not include software that causes unintentional harm due to some deficiency. The term badware is sometimes used, and applied to both true (malicious) malware and unintentionally harmful software.[2]

So IMO...

Is it a software used to:

- `Disrupt computer operations?` Maybe it's not designed or used to do that, but unfortunately can lead to disrupting computer operations. *My opinion: **almost is**.*
- `Gather sensitive information?` If you don't pay enough attention its downloads and install a software that gather sensitive information. *My opinion: **it is***.
- `Gain access to private computer systems?` *Fortunately it seems to **not do that***.

Is it:

- `Defined by its malicious intent?` *My opinion: **it is trying really hard** to be*.
- `Acting against the requirements of the computer user?` *It **definitively do***.

And:

- `Malware does not include software that causes unintentional harm due to some deficiency.` *Its **operations definitively are intentional and carefully planed**.*

So objectively it subjectively can be a malware and it definitively objectively is a **badware** ;)

Comment: One could easily argue that forcing/tricking everyone onto Windows 10, whether they want it or not (which seems to be the intent of GWX) **is** malicious.

Comment: @user20574 That's why I have used: IMO, my opinion and subjectively ;)

Answer (score 2):

It is technically not malware (causes no damage), but I call it [Potentially unwanted program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentially_unwanted_program). It is an advertising tool to annoy users to upgrade to their latest Windows.

Comment: Of course it causes damage, if your internet connection has a data cap, Microsoft has effectively stolen your data. And no the argument of "get an unlimited connection" isn't a valid one as a these can be either more expensive or not available or may just not be needed and perfectly adequate otherwise.

Comment: And what is a time lost on paying attention to accidentally don't install W10?!? Aren't an unwanted installation (especially in production environment or without drivers in W10), bandwidth and diskspace lost to download W10 a damages?

Comment: And time spent waiting for the installer, then the uninstaller, with which you could be doing something productive.

Comment: Stealing 6GB of my available disk space is hardly "no damage" either.

Comment: *"...It is technically not malware (causes no damage)..."* -the [Morris Worm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morris_worm) did not cause any damage, either. But Robert Morris was tried and convicted of violating United States Code: Title 18 (18 U.S.C. § 1030).

Answer (score 0):

No, this program does **not** fall into the malware category, as the program does *zero* damage against your computer, does not breach any privacy.

Comment: It entices users to degrade their own privacy by installing Windows 10.

Comment: Of course it causes harm - it uses up your data allowance by downloading Windows 10 in the background. Some people have a limited data allowance - and in this case, Microsoft has actively stolen from their data allowance WITHOUT advising the user they would do so. (The associated Windows Update only claims 400-700 odd KB of size)

Comment: It may also have non-obvious costs. I've seen it on many, many, many Windows 7 computers in institutions such as universities and hospitals, where it's eating up hard drive space. Sure, you could blame the administrators, but it doesn't meant that it's not doing damage.

Comment: How do you know that it isn't breaching privacy?  For that matter, isn't there plenty of evidence that it ***does*** breach privacy?

Comment: *"...as the program does zero damage against your computer..."* -the [Morris Worm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morris_worm) did not cause any damage, either. But Robert Morris was tried and convicted of violating United States Code: Title 18 (18 U.S.C. § 1030). I have spent countless hours removing it because of the endless stream of nags it produces. This malware has likely caused millions of users hundreds of millions of hours of lost productivity and endless frustration.

Answer (score 0):

the way it subverts  the owner and tries to force itself on us. it is very much like a Trojan down loader and indefinably  is legalized malware, any process that behaves in a way that reduces the usability of a system.. is a malicious program gwx.exe  creates  hidden folders and  then  prevents the removal of said folders by ordinary means. it also is installed without consent of the user/owner of the system and  that is not ethical or acceptable.
it also intentionally slows down the system i have done a lot of experimenting on this. the longer you ignore it the more it slows down the system  i tested this on a system with two 3.6 ghz quad core processors, the other dirty thing it does is if you do disable it it messes with  the trusted installer and make-cab  processes. this results in  the trusted installer  taking over all the ram  or cpu bandwidth or both at the same time  rendering the system useless my system  with dual quads @3.6 ghz and 32gb of ddr3 ram was rendered useless by this thing for 29 hours. and  it results in logs in the cbs logs folder that reach sizes as big as 26gb and its not one log file that size. it makes many of them  and will do so until  the drive is full (verified by allowing this crap to run undisturbed for 76 hours it finally stopped when it ran out of space on a 3 tb drive and crashed the system)

Comment: This is more of a rant than an answer.

Comment: well  i was a bit cross about it mostly because like the majority of people im happy with my windows 7. and dont appreciate having to  spend almost 2 weeks trying to get rid of Microsoft hostage ware. that should never have been on my systems in the first place? i think everyone can agree that this  UN invited spam in a can is pretty low even for  Microsoft.

Comment: the exe file is a tool i dug up off  the web that disables silent os upgrades and also gets rid of the gwx problem. and  no that file is not hosted from  a local drive its hosted from a nas server  i manage at work its also available by email request. <skysongsf.es@gmail.com)  i have used this on all  the systems  i manage with only a few  issues on  some of the more abused units.

Comment: Additional note: Disabling automatic updates appears to trigger a bug in Windows Update where, after some time, it will eat all your memory and slow your computer to a crawl. (The only workaround I know is to stop the Windows Update service when/if this happens, and start it again later if you want to install updates)