# Windows 10 roll back to Windows 7 pro

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade

I upgraded from Windows 7 to 10 but didn't like it, so I rolled back to Windows 7 sp1 pro, but not without problems!

When I'm trying to use Windows upgrade I get the message "Windows 10 couldn't be installed" Error code 1900101-30018.

It's very annoying since the update doesn't seem to work anymore.

Do you have any clues? Any help is appreciated, I've tried everything (obviously not), and spend a lot of time on nothing!

Comment: look if the tips from Microsoft help: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/error-when-upgrading-to-windows-10-0xc1900101/0e1c698a-6ea2-4bf0-aad4-0a26604f3200

Comment: Thanks, but the the usual BS from MIcrosoft, an impossible task they're  suggesting. I suppose I just have to live with it, but thanks anyway ..

Comment: which Av suite and other 3rd party tool do you use?

Comment: I'm using ESET smart security ver. 9.0.318.20 , I've tried to disable it, but it didn't make any difference !

Comment: uninstall it completely. Also disable all other 3rd party tools from startup (Clean boot). Also update all drivers. Now do the upgrade.

Comment: My mistake, I should have written when i try to use windows update and not upgrade, I'm trying to update my windows 7, when I get the message, I can't get rid of windows 10, and I do not want it, sorry :(  ..

Comment: So you now no longer want to upgrade to Win10? If yes, follow this: http://superuser.com/questions/922068/how-to-disable-the-get-windows-10-icon-shown-in-the-notification-area-tray

Comment: No, I don't ! I looked at your link, it's not that simple! I've removed everything from my PC, except what's causing the error message in the windows update, Microsoft has been very invasive, and screwed up many Computers !!! ..

Comment: share the setup logs (setuperr.log) from C:\$Windows.~BT\Sources\panther\. Maybe it shows some details.