# How do I completely and permanently remove all traces of Flash from Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, flash, windows-10-v1607

I know I can disable Flash in Edge and individually in the other browsers.
However I don't want any trace to remain of Flash on my system.

I've googled all around, but nowhere can I get a tool or tutorial that will fully remove all traces of Flash.

I cannot tell you how much I loath that piece of malware.

How do I completely and permanently remove all traces of Flash from Windows 10?

[This answer helps with the files](https://superuser.com/questions/497095/how-to-delete-trustedinstaller-files-on-windows-8), but I'm still stuck on the registry keys.

Comment: You can only disable it not remove it: http://www.howtogeek.com/222275/how-to-uninstall-and-disable-flash-in-every-web-browser/

Comment: You misunderstand, I want it gone, nuked from orbit. Whatever it takes.

Comment: Not possible!  Remove edge if that's not enough.  That will disable the Windows Store though.

Comment: @Ramhound, there is no such thing as not possible. You can take ownership of the files and delete them one by one. There **is** a way.  I'm just hoping for a better way than taking ownership of every single flash file on the system and deleting them one at a time and then wading through the registry to do the same.

Comment: Flash is built into the Edge engine...

Comment: No it is not. There are flash files on the system and in the registry that can be deleted. Without those it will not work. I just want these to be gone and stay gone. The only problem is that these are owned by TrustedInstaller.

Comment: Flash is NOT malware, it is a good platform for old browser games!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download [this tool](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/152688-win6x_registry_tweak/), open a [cmd as admin](https://superuser.com/a/1067983/174557) and run

```
install_wim_tweak.exe /o /c Adobe-Flash-For-Windows /r
```

This kills the 2 Flash packages in Windows 10. After a reboot it is gone.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `/r` at the end to actually have it removed? Your Windows 8 reply was having one: https://superuser.com/a/559166/24905

Comment: @Mecki correct, I've added it

Comment: Does this remove flash from chromium-based browsers, which contain their own patched versions of flash?

Comment: @JW0914 no, only the flash player that is used by IE/Edge